# Android source code repo sync issue

Tags: android, git, repository

I am using ubuntu 11.10.
I am doing android source code download process... i was trying to get the sources for the 4.0.1 release... but the repo sync operation keeps running about 8 hrs and still it continues and another issue is repo like samsung/tuna/ 501% downloaded
Any one can tell me what was the max hours for downloading process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it took me around 12 hours to download it on 2 MBps line,, it was around 16 GB of code base.

Comment: Is this whole source code 16GB,or 4.0.3 only? mean you run "repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest" or "repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-4.0.1_r1" command.

Comment: If you get chance please look this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18426844/android-source-code-download-stop-after-100-what-is-next-step